# Why does my binary search produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I am using Eclipse. This is my code:

```
private int binarySearch(int[] arraySorted, int value, int min, int max) {
    if (max < min) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int mid = min + max / 2;
        if (value > arraySorted[mid]) // LINE 22
            return binarySearch(arraySorted, value, mid + 1, max);
        else if (value < arraySorted[mid])
            return binarySearch(arraySorted, value, min, mid - 1);
        else
            return mid;
    }
}
```

and this is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Launcher.binarySearch(Launcher.java:22)
at Launcher.binarySearch(Launcher.java:23)
at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:14)
```

I call the method like so:

```
int[] arraySorted = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 7, 99 };
binarySearch(arraySorted, searchNum, 0, arraySorted.length - 1);
```

Can anyone figure out why I am getting this? How can I identify the issue by using the debugger?

Comment: Take a look at the values of `min` and `max`, and then see if the value of `mid` is what you were expecting.

Comment: what is the value of searchNum ?

Comment: You need to purchase some parentheses. After you have them, try `int mid = (min + max) / 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle index element is calculated incorrectly because of the missing parentheses.

It should be:

```
int mid = (min + max) / 2;
```

and not

```
int mid = min + max / 2;
```

which calculates, adding unnecessary parentheses, `min + (max / 2)`.

You can easily find out this is the problem by doing a step-by-step analysis of your code with your favorite debugger.